# How to retrieve file names and subdirectory names from a directory in C?

Tags: c, file, file-io, directory

Ok I have something like this:

```
struct dirent *dp;
DIR *dir;
char fullname[MAXPATHLEN];
char** tmp_paths = argv[1]; //Not the exact code but you get the idea.

...

while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
{
    struct stat stat_buffer;

    sprintf(fullname, "%s/%s", *tmp_paths, dp->d_name);

    if (stat(fullname, &stat_buffer) != 0)
        perror(opts.programname);

    /* Processing files */
    if (S_ISDIR(stat_buffer.st_mode))
    {
        nSubdirs++;
        DIRECTORYINFO* subd = malloc(BUFSIZ);
    }

    /* Processing subdirs */
    if (S_ISREG(stat_buffer.st_mode))
    {
        nFiles++;
        FILEINFO *f = malloc(BUFSIZ);
    }
}
```

How do I go about reading in the file names and subdirectory names into my own structure DIRECTORYINFO and FILEINFO? I've gone through stat.h and haven't found anything useful.

Comment: directories are an OS feature and not part of C. You have to specify the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UNIX world the name is not part of the file, so `stat(2)` cannot retrieve information about it. But in your code you have the name as `dp->d_name`, so you can copy that string into your own data structure. That should be fairly simple.

If this is not your problem I didn't understand the question.

Comment: Yup that works thanks. It's just that I was under the impression that d_name only works for directories.

Comment: It is very common for the `struct` types in UNIX that the fields are prefixed with a common *something* and an underscore. For example `struct dirent` has `d_*`, `struct stat` has `st_*`, `struct time` has `tm_*`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607945/listing-directories-in-linux-from-c/2608066#2608066) question and its answers. You probably want to use `dirent->d_name`.

Answer (score 0):

**Glob is your friend**

*The **glob()** function searches for all  the  pathnames  matching  pattern according  to  the  rules  used  by  the shell*

```
/* Sample Code */
#include <glob.h>    
glob_t data;
glob("*", 0, NULL, &data ); /* Here "*" says to match all files of the current dir */
for(int i=0; i<data.gl_pathc; i++)
{
    /* Printing all the path names,Just for illustration */
    printf( "%s\n", data.gl_pathv[i] );
}
/* To split into DIRINFO and FILEINFO, stat(2) should be made use of */
globfree( &data ); /* free the data structure */
```

To get more details you can always use the unix **man** [page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob)

> **man glob**